# Trouble installing packages in a fresh chroot

Tags: apt, package-management, chroot

I created a chroot using the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot), substituting `focal` for `lucid`. Now I'd like to start installing packages, starting with Python, but I'm not sure what kind of setup I need to perform before doing so.

Currently when I try to install `software-properties-common` (via `apt-get`), I get the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
software-properties-common : Depends: gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 (>= 1.1.0-2) but it 
is not installable
                             Depends: packagekit but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Googling tells me that `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` might turn something up, but it does not.

I thought it might be an issue with `/etc/apt/sources.list`, so I copied that in from the outer installation and refreshed but it didn't change anything.

Edit:

Running `sudo apt update` gives the following output:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 1s (440 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
69 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: "*unmet dependencies*" usually means that your package sources are introducing a version conflict. "*it is not installable*" also strongly suggests that you have mucked up your sources. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1390184/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: Please [edit] to include `apt-cache policy gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0` and `apt-cache policy packagekit` and `apt-cache policy software-properties-common`